# Properties of the KL topology [reference request]

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, references, kullback-leibler, probability-inequalities

I'm trying to understand better what are the implications of a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converging toward some limit $X$ in the KL topology, ie the probability density functions are such that:

$$ KL(p,p_n) \rightarrow 0 $$

[From the Pinsker inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality) we know that this convergence is stronger than convergence in total variation, which is in turn stronger than weak convergence, but I'm having a hard time finding results detailling in what aspects this convergence is stronger, and other elementary properties of this topology

Here a few questions I'm asking myself. Do you know any good reference that might tackle them and/or other properties of the KL topology ?

1. Does convergence of $KL(p_n,p)$ to 0 imply convergence of $KL(p,p_n)$ to 0 ? In other words are there two or only one KL topology ?
2. Does KL convergence imply convergence of some interesting unbounded functions like the mean, variance and higher moments ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Interesting questions. My gut feeling is that 1) can not be true in general. The following paper of Harremoes is relevant, but, I don't think it answers your question: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1023703&tag=1. I am too eager to know the answer for 2)

Comment: Hey. I have since come up with an example where KL(p_n,p) goes to 0 but not the other way around (it's in fact easy to find guys like that). I still don't have a good answer to 2). I need to edit my question to reflect this new info

Comment: Hi, I realise this is an old question, but could you say a bit (or give a reference) about what's meant by "KL topology" here? As in, what is the definition of an open set, according to this topology?